# A new FontStyle is applied to different locations in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, selection

I'm trying to write a program that automatically formats a bibliography, it works with the following pattern:

```
int ct = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += ct.ToString() + textBox1.Text;
    richTextBox1.Text += textBox2.Text;
    richTextBox1.Text += "\n\r";
    ct = ct + 1;
}
```

That works well, the thing is I want the text from the second textBox to be in italic. When I try to use

```
richTextBox1.Find(textBox2.Text, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
```

then only the last "textBox2.Text" is italicized; previous ones are resetted to regular font. I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me how I can correct this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using StringReader and a second form:

```
    int ct = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "\n\r";
        richTextBox1.Text += ct.ToString()+". "+textBox1.Text;
        richTextBox1.Text += ", " + textBox2.Text;
        form2.richTextBox1.Text += textBox2.Text + "\n";
        ct = ct + 1;
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(form2.richTextBox1.Text))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ct; i++)
            {
                string A = reader.ReadLine();
                richTextBox1.Find(A, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
            }
        }
    }
```